# Looping over a list - 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, pypdf

I've uploaded a PDF using PyPDF2. Here's my code:

```
PageNo=list(range(0,pfr.numPages))

for i in PageNo:
    pg = writer.addPage(i)
```

PageNo creates a list of all the page numbers and I'm trying to add each page from the list into a new PDF, but when I run this script, I'm getting 'int' object is not subscriptable. I know it's an error in my for loop, and I'm sure it's obvious, but any insight on my mistake above would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Edit - here's the solution:

```
for i in list(range(0,pfr.numPages))
     pg = pfr.getPage(i)
     writer.addPage(pg)
```

Comment: What about `for i in range(0,len(PageNo)):`? Will you show us the list `PageNo` made ?

Comment: Could you post the stack trace for the error? (e.g. the complete error dump)

Comment: Got it working! I needed to to define a new variable in my for loop before I passed it through writer.addPage

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing more code, like what exactly is pfr.numPages? Where is it created? How is it used? the error is happening because `PageNo` is being evaluated as an `int`, so its less likely its an error in your for loop and more likely an error in your list. Assuming `pfr.numPages` is an array of some type, try this:

```
for i in range(0, len(pfr.numPages)):
    pg = writer.addPage(prf.numPages[i])
```

However as mentioned before, if `PageNo` is being evaluated as an int, then pfr.numPages isn't an array or its an array with one element. Pay close attention to the trace if this errors, it will tell you which line, and if it says int is not subscriptable on the line with `prf.numPages`, then you know that your problem is deeper than this for loop.

Comment: You are using `prf.numPages[i]` in your loop, it means that `prf.numPages` is a list. So how can use use `pfr.numPages` as integer in `for i in range(0, pfr.numPages):`?

Comment: Good catch! Thank you I forgot to add `len` .

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Turns out the issue was that I needed to define the variable before it was passed through writer.addPage. 

for i in list(range(0,pfr.numPages)):
     pg = pfr.getPage(i)
     writer.addPage(pg)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that `writer` is a `PdfFileWriter` object. In that case, you will have to pass a page retrieved from `pfr` to the `writer.addPage` method, instead of passing an integer.

```
for i in pfr.pages:
    writer.addPage(i)
```